# joining a reference table but issue if trying to join with no value in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

let's say I have a table with data, where I'm storing ID's such as 1, 2, 3. I'm trying to get a text value from a reference table, however, if a particular row, does not have a value in it, then that entire row disappears.

table structure below:

```
 tblData
 clientID        ReasonID          OtherID
 12              1                 17
 15              NULL              18



 tblReference
 FldName         ID              Label
 Reasons         1               Terminated
 Reasons         2               Absent
```

I'm basically hoping to join tblData with tblReference, using ReasonID however, if the ReasonID is NULL in tableData I don't want that entire row to disaapear. I still need to see the NULL. I'm joining on 20 different fields and I've just realized that I'm missing rows because some of them have NULL as values. I still need to see NULL's!!!

Here's what I've tried...

```
 Select tblData.ClientID, tblData.ReasonId,tblReference.Label, tblData.OtherID from tblData 
 LEFT JOIN
 tblReference on tblData.ReasonID=tblReference.ID
 WHERE FldName='Reasons'
```

I also tried Inner JOIN but does not work either. Any ideas?

DESIRED END RESULT:

```
 clientID        ReasonID   Label           OtherID
 12              1          Terminated      17
 15              NULL       NULL            18
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS reference every column by the alias so this kind of thing doesn't happen. You need to move FldName = 'Reason' to the where clause. In the where clause is has turned your left join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on the second table in a `left join` need to be in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause:

```
Select d.ClientID, d.ReasonId, r.Label, d.OtherID
from tblData d left join
     tblReference r
     on d.ReasonID = r.ID and r.FldName = 'Reasons';
```

In your formulation, the `where` condition turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Just put an OR condition on the join similar to this:

```
ON (Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 or Table1.Col1 is NULL and Table2.Col1 is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

following query does what you need.

```
Select tblData.ClientID, 
tblData.ReasonId,tblReference.Label, 
tblData.OtherID 
from tblData LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReference 
on tblData.ReasonID=tblReference.ID 
AND FldName ='Reasons'
```

Here is a complete script which creates temporary tables insert data in them and show the query in action

```
DECLARE @Date TABLE
(
    ClientID INT,
    ReasonID INT NULL,
    OtherID INT NULL
)

DECLARE @Reference TABLE
(
    Name VARCHAR(MAX),
    ID INT,
    Label VARCHAR(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO @Date(ClientID, ReasonID, OtherID) VALUES (12, 1, 17)
INSERT INTO @Date(ClientID, ReasonID, OtherID) VALUES (15, NULL, 18)

INSERT INTO @Reference(Name, ID, Label) VALUES ('Reasons', 1, 'Terminated')
INSERT INTO @Reference(Name, ID, Label) VALUES ('Reasons', 2, 'Absent')

SELECT * FROM  @Date D LEFT OUTER JOIN  @Reference R ON D.ReasonID = R.ID AND R.Name='Reasons'
```